# Why is @Input property undefined in ngOnInit?

Tags: angular

In this component I use a service to get some data from an API

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-question-presenter',
  template: `
    <div class="question-presenter">
      <app-question [question]="question"></app-question>
    </div>
  `
})
export class QuestionPresenterComponent implements OnInit {
  private requestId: string;
  private userId: string;
  private question: Question;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private questionService: QuestionService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap((params: Params) => {
        return this.questionService.getQuestion(params.requestId);
      })
    ).subscribe((data: any) => this.question = data.data[0].question);
  }
}
```

In another component (the one that provides `app-question`) I am trying to access `question` but getting `undefined` in the console.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-question',
  templateUrl: './question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question.component.scss']
})
export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  question: Question;

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.question);
  }
```

I know that the data is making it to the template (because it renders as expected) but I thought that the `Input` would be loaded before calling `ngOnInit` - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because you're getting question asynchronously so it needs time to update that input. There are many ways to fix it: `ngIf`, `setter`, `ngOnChanges`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delay creation of the component until the value is ready.

```html
<app-question *ngIf="question" [question]="question"></app-question>
```

You can also use an observable

```
 this.question$ = this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap(({requestId) => this.questionService.getQuestion(requestId))
 )
```

Then in the template:

```
<app-question *ngIf="question$ | async as question" [question]="question"></app-question>
```

Comment: D'oh; I had the `*ngIf="question"` in my `question.component.html` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a race condition going on. If you're worried about it displaying only on the template, you can add an **Async Pipe** to the property you're binding to. It will only show once the property has a value. This will subscribe to the question property and unsubscribe appropriately.

*html*

```
<div>
 <p>{{question | async }}</p>
</div>
```

If you're looking to use the variable in the component itself, I would **subscribe** to the question property in your QuestionPresenterComponent.

To make it even cleaner, I would suggest putting that variable in a shared service, along with your API call, that way all of the subscribers would inherit the updates accordingly.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-question',
  templateUrl: './question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question.component.scss']
})
export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  question: Question;

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.question.subscribe(question => {
        console.log(question)
    });
  }
```